# How to stop vanity url for sub-directory in domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, vanity-url

I have created a login interface where user can register there username. Now i wanted to give each user a vanity url like, example.com/user. I am using .htaccess rewrite conditions and php for that. Everything is working fine except when i try a url like **example.com/chat/xx** it displays a profile page with "xx" id. Instead it should have thrown a 404 page(thats what i want). I want that vanity url thing only works if a user input "example.com/user" not in sub directory like "example.com/xyz/user". Is this possible ?

htaccess --

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} >""
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Php used --

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
// fetching user data and displaying it
else
header(location:index.php);
```

Comment: you'd want a negative lookahead assertion to disallow any `/` in the captured text. Check out: http://serverfault.com/questions/120971/regex-negative-look-ahead-is-not-working-for-mod-rewrite-between-different-apach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you must match on an URL-path without slashes `/` only

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([^/\.]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This regular expression `^([^\.]+)$` matches everything *without* a dot `.`, e.g.

- a
- bcd
- hello/how/are/you
- chat/xx

but it doesn't match

- test.php
- hello.world
- chat/xx.bar

This one `^/?([^/\.]+)$` works the same, except it disallows slashes `/` too. I.e. it allows everything, except URL-paths, containing either dot `.` or slash `/`.

For more details on Apache's regular expressions, see [Glossary - Regular Expression (Regex)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/glossary.html#regex) and [Rewrite Intro - Regular Expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex).

Comment: Thanks. This works like a charm, but can you explain how this works ? or provide me a reference link ?

Comment: @KushSharma I tried to explain the regex a bit, I hope it makes it clear enough. There's some info on regex at the Apache website, but you can look at any website describing regular expressions or PCRE.